# Checkboxes in a table and values post

Tags: python, html, django, post, checkbox

I'm new on django and I wish to POST checkboxes values from a view to another view.

This is the snippet:

When I check the two only checkboxes that are in my table rows I have only one value (from Django debug window):

```
Variable                   Value

csrfmiddlewaretoken        u'6i8aRyhvTq29EOy6sfffzPtKy9jXUsVi'
Login                      u'jhgjghj'
```

but the post objects should be:

```
Variable                   Value

csrfmiddlewaretoken        u'6i8aRyhvTq29EOy6sfffzPtKy9jXUsVi'
Login                      u'jhgjghj'
Login                      u'sdfsfd'  (the second object not posted)
```

In addition I have a second problem.

This is the view to which I pass these POST data:

```
def deleteObjects(request):
template = 'delObj.html'
objects = []
for obj in request.POST.items():
    if obj('Login'):
        todelete = Login.objects.get(obj('Login'))
        objects.append(todelete)
context = {'objects' : objects}
return render(request, template, context)
```

I get an error "Tuple object is not callable" (for the row if obj('name') == 'Login':), but i can't understand why.
Aren't POST data elements KEY and VALUE of a dict-like object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, POST is a dict-like object, but you seem to have a misunderstanding about how those work.  `items()` returns a tuple of (key, value) for each item in the dict - so, for example, obj would be `('Login', 'jhghghj')`. So it makes no sense to say `obj('Login')`: obj is not callable, and neither is it accessed via dict notation (which would be `obj['login']`). Instead you would want this:

```
for key, value in request.POST.items():
   if key == 'Login':
       todelete = Login.objects.get(value)
```

However, and here's where we get to your first problem, I can't understand why you want to iterate through at all. Like you said, request.POST is a dict-like object, and you want a single key, `Login`. So normally you would simply get the value of `Login` via `request.POST['Login']` - except that you have two values for `Login`, and the reason POST is only dict-like and not actually a dict is that it defines a `getlist` method for exactly this use case. So, this is what you want:

```
for value in request.POST.getlist('Login'):
    todelete = Login.objects.get(value)
```

Comment: You're right in a dict, keys are unique.
In detail I want to identify the type of objects passed via POST request, so the view which receives objects can identify the Model (this view must display "Are you sure to delete these objects?", in this case the model is 'Login'), but I think I have to write a view for every model I want to delete objects and omit 'name' for checkboxes. Thank you so much